# Retrieving favorites (i.e. likes) from Facebook Graph API or FQL in the user's order

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

When viewing your favorites from the front-end of facebook.com at `facebook.com/[username]/favorites`, those favorites can be arranged with the first five showing up as thumbnails.

Is it possible to retrieve the likes from the api in the same order defined by the user on their profile?  It doesn't seem possible based on what I've found with playing around with `/me/music` and poking around the fql tables.

It seems to me that we can create more meaningful apps for Facebook users if we are able to know how they have ordered their favorites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest Facebook design (June 2013), it's no longer possible to edit the order various likes appear on your profile.  So this question is moot.